# Redux RTK optimistic update causes Immer error

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, rtk-query, immer.js

I've followed the docs (and some other posts) about RTK optimistic updates but I can't seem to get my case to work. Here is my createReply mutation:

```
createReply: builder.mutation<IPost, any>({
  query({...body}) {
    return {
      url: PostPath,
      method: 'POST',
      body: body,
    };
  },
  async onQueryStarted({...body}, {dispatch, queryFulfilled}) {

    const patchResult = dispatch(
      resourcesApi.util.updateQueryData('getRepliesById', body.parent, (draft) => {
        console.log(draft);
        Object.assign(draft, body)
      })
    )
    try {
      await queryFulfilled
    } catch {
      console.log("query was fulfilled");
      console.log(patchResult);
      // patchResult.undo()
    }
  }
}),
```

and this is the `getRepliesById` query that it's referencing:

```
getRepliesById: builder.query<IPost, string>({
  query: (id: string) => `${PostPath}/${id}/replies`,
}),
```

When I try to use this mutation, the POST works fine, but I'm given this error:
`[Immer] Immer only supports setting array indices and the 'length' property`.
(The error call stack ends with `onQueryStarted`).

Where here am I going against Immer rules?

Edit; Here is `body`:

```
const postObj = {
  content: reply,
  author: user._id,
  parent: _parentId,
  visibility: {scope: 'public'},
  media: [],
  ats: [],
  kind: 'comment',
};
createReply(postObj);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `data` is an array and now you are working with it as if it were an `object`. An array can only have number-indexed properties and your `Object.assign` seems to add other properties than that?

Comment: I've edited my question to show the post object, assuming that's what you mean by `data`? It's an object from the beginning.

Comment: The error message says that the value `useGetRepliesByIdQuery(body.parent).data` is an array, not an object. And that's what you are trying to update there.

Comment: Ah I see, my issue ended up being an improper typing so I wasn't able to do a `draft.push(body)`. Fixed that up and now I'm able to handle it as an array; thanks for the direction.